# implementing a barrier issue

Tags: linux, pthreads

```
static int barrier_counter = 0;
pthread_cond_t condition;

pthread_mutex_t local_lock;
int init_barrier(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    barrier_counter = n;
    pthread_mutex_init(&local_lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condition, NULL);
    return 0;
}
int barrier() {

    pthread_mutex_trylock(&local_lock);
    barrier_counter--;
    printf("inside barrier befor the while n is : %d \n",barrier_counter );
    while (0 < barrier_counter) {
        printf("inside the barrier n is : %d\n", barrier_counter);
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition,&local_lock);
    }
    printf("befor bordcast : %d \n",barrier_counter );
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
    printf("done the brodcast when n is : %d \n",barrier_counter );
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&local_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

we tried to implement barrier but somehow we dont get to do broadcast and we finish anyway.
we dont even get deadlock, there are few threads that are actually waiting but not the amount we specified in init_barrier.

Comment: Don't use trylock here, it might fail, which would make your `pthread_cond_wait` probably not work as expected. also, why not use pthread's barriers?

Comment: @artlessnoise, this is not about memory barriers.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thx.  Removing the *linux-kernel* tag probably made sense.

Comment: @Hasturkun: You should add that as an answer - it's almost certainly the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) requires a locked mutex. Your call to `pthread_mutex_trylock()` might fail, and so continue without acquiring the mutex.

I suggest you use [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) instead.

Also, unless you're looking to re-implement barriers, You should use [`pthread_barrier_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html) and [`pthread_barrier_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html).